# phpmyadmin security

Tags: php, apache2, phpmyadmin

I have a production server with apache2, php, mysql.
I have just one site right now (mysite.com) as a virtual host.  I want to put phpmyadmin, webalizer, and maybe webmin on there.  So far, I installed phpmyadmin, and it works but the whole internet can go to mysite.com/phpmyadmin

How can I reduce the visibility to say 192.168.0.0/16 so it's just accessible to machines behind my firewall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) You can do it at the Webserver level.**

Use allow/deny rules for apache. If you don't have direct access to your apache configuration file, you may use a .htaccess file.

```
<Directory /docroot>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.1.2.3
</Directory>
```

**2) You can do it at the application level using the phpmyadmin config file.**

The configuration parameter is: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']`

Examples of rules are:

```
'all' -> 0.0.0.0/0
'localhost' -> 127.0.0.1/8
'localnetA' -> SERVER_ADDRESS/8
'localnetB' -> SERVER_ADDRESS/16
'localnetC' -> SERVER_ADDRESS/24
```

You can see this on the official phpMyAdmin configuration documentation.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#servers_allowdeny_order

Comment: I did option #2 with adding /usr/share/phpmyadmin to allow 192.168.0.0/16 and it seems to have worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Option 2 is the way to go. Simpler, and I'd rather block it before it got to running any PHP period.

Comment: Okay, I moved the Apache option in the first place.

Comment: So that people don't get confused: for all comments earlier than that one, when they say option #2 they're actually referring to the Webserver option.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a module in Apache called [mod_access](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html)

You can either configure it in your apache config file or within a .htaccess file in the directory's root.

Here's a short example

```
<Directory /your_folder/location>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
   Allow from 123.123.123.123
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [<Location>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) directive (either in server configuration or if it is allowed, in .htaccess). In there, you can use `Allow from` to deny access to everyone else *except* some certain source.